# CouchDB Views (map/reduce)

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb

I have documents similar to this in CouchDB 1.6.1:

```
 "_id": "test_test",
 "_rev": "4-8eb22214f7f3dccd3c979f95ded0a7b0",
 "test": {
   "sample": {
       "abc": {
           "aaa": 877,
           "bbb": 202,
           "ccc": 0,
           "ddd": 362,
           "eee": 242,
           "ggg": 81
       },
       "def": {
           "aaa": 697,
           "bbb": 233,
           "ccc": 0,
           "ddd": 178,
           "eee": 90,
           "ggg": 5
       },
       "ghi": {
           "aaa": 987,
           "bbb": 396,
           "ccc": 0,
           "ddd": 399,
           "eee": 178,
           "ggg": 108
       },
       "jkl": {
           "aaa": 1165,
           "bbb": 332,
           "ccc": 0,
           "ddd": 286,
           "eee": 173,
           "ggg": 100
       },
```

I wish to extract data from this such as:

```
1)

"test": {
"sample": {
   "abc": {
       "aaa": 877,
   "def": {
       "aaa": 697,
   "ghi": {
       "aaa": 987, etc.
```

or:

```
2)
"test": {
"sample": {
   "def": {
       "aaa": 697,
       "bbb": 233,
       "ccc": 0,
       "ddd": 178,
       "eee": 90,
       "ggg": 5
   },
```

I wish also to be able to get totals for all docs with `'test'` or all docs with `'sample'` or all the docs with `'def'` or all docs with `'aaa'`.

I have a map javascript as follows:

```
function(doc) {
if(doc.test.sample.abc.aaa){
emit(null, doc.test.sample.abc.aaa);
}
}
```

This correctly gives a single value (877)

I have also tried

```
function(doc) {
for (var i in doc.test.sample.abc){
emit(doc.test.sample.abc[i], null);
}
}
```

Hoping to get:

```
 "aaa": 877,
 "bbb": 202,
 "ccc": 0,
 "ddd": 362,
 "eee": 242,
 "ggg": 81
```

Sometimes one succeeds with map/reduce and sometimes nothing works.

Looping through fields seems to be difficult.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**:

Sample code from the "Change Notifications, Filters" section of [CouchDB The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html)

```
{
"_id": "_design/app",
"_rev": "1-b20db05077a51944afd11dcb3a6f18f1",
"filters": {
"important": "function(doc, req) { if(doc.priority == 'high') { return true; }
else { return false; }}"
}
}
```

If I paste this code into CouchDB it is rejected.
It also fails the JSONLint test.
I have tried minifying it with the same results.
What am I not seeing here?
Code quoted in "Answer 2" below PASSES the JSONLint test and CouchDB accepts it.
However, as soon as one starts to enter specific functions, things go wrong.
Is there a way of dealing with this please.
Many thanks again.

**Edit2**:

I am nearly there??

This code is accepted by Couch:

```
{
"_id": "_design/lists",
"_rev": "3-628dc2f53051971994043c2e0bfc44ea",
"language": "javascript",
"views": {
   "list_setup": {
       "map": "function(doc) {if(doc.compartment.number){  emit(null,   doc.compartment.number);}}"
   }
},
"lists": {
   "first_list": "function(head, req) {var result = []; while (row = getRow()) { if (row !== null) {  row.key  + row.value  else{ send(JSON.stringify({status_code: 404}));}}send(JSON.stringify(result));}}"
}
}
```

However, if I run curl, I get

```
{"error":"compilation_error","reason":"Expression does not eval to a function. (function(head, req) {var result = []; while (row = getRow()) { if (row !== null) {  row.key  + row.value  else{ send(JSON.stringify({status_code: 404}));}}send(JSON.stringify(result));}})"}
```

I am not sure what to do with the `row.key  + row.value` part of the function.

Sorry this took so long.

Comment: Can you clarify me the question? You need help for your mapping function on the test.sample.abc childs ?

Comment: Alexis Côté I need help for instance with obtaining   option  1) above.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your first option you can use a combination of a map and a list function.

With your map function you create an index for all your documents

```
function(doc){
  emit(null, doc._id);
}
```

If you whant to query your view a little bit more specific, you have to emit this specific value.

The next part is the list function. If you query your view with "include_docs=true" you get the whole document back. Building on that you can use a list function to format the "pre"result. Every result from the map function lies inside an array which contains objects (every object is 
equivalent to a document).

This is my list function pattern:

```
function(head, req) {
   var result = [];

   while (row = getRow()) {
      if (row !== null) {
         // make your formatting here
      else{
         send(JSON.stringify({
            status_code: 404
         }));
      }
   }

   send(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

The final query looks like this

curl -X GET -g 'http://[host]:[port]/[db]/_design/[ddoc name]/_list/[list func name]/[map func name]?[query]&include_docs=true'

As a reference, here the official doc: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/render.html#db-design-design-doc-list-list-name-view-name

Comment: Actually it is not that hard to understand. Don't be afraid of my list function pattern. 

Firstly I would recommend to get in touch with JSON formatting with JavaScript. For a better understanding put on one side your initial document and on the other side what you actual want. After that look how to format everything with JavaScript. As a hint JSON documents in JavaScript are simply objects and arrays. So you just have to rearrange your documents. If you have that put you code in my list function pattern. 

http://www.json.org/
http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter4.html

Comment: Basically I did not know how to set this up in Futon. Various websites and your reference were good with explanations but I did not know where to insert the list code. I set up a new view, inserted your map function but it is not clear to me where I set up the list (or show) code. does it come in the "map" area of futon, or somewhere else? I also tried to insert it as a list below the map function but could not get it set up properly and futon would not accept it. Many thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete reference for all functions which could be in a design document. I hope i don't missed any brackets ;)

```
{
   "_id": "_design/[ddoc name]",

   "views": {
      "[view name]": {
         "map": "[map function]"
      }
   },
   "language": "javascript",
   "lists": {
      "[list name]": "[list function]"
   },
   "shows": {
      "[show name]": "[show function]"
   },
   "updates": {
       "[update name]": "[update function]"
   },
   "filters": {
      "[filter name]": "[filter function]"
   }
}
```

It is also very important that you minify your JavaScript code.

Comment: Hi @Sceada. Please see my edit above. Thank you for your trouble. This is obviously an important part of CouchDB.

Comment: Hi @Sceada. Please see my edit2 above. Its taken me a long time. If your patience is still holding out.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my late response. I was on vacation. Your syntax is not correct.

```
function(head, req) {
  var result = [];
  while (row = getRow()) {
      if (row !== null) {
          // This is not correct, you have to assigne the result to a  
          // variable. 
          // You also have to assigne something to the array result.
          // result.append();
          // So if row.key and row.value are both numbers and you want
          // the result you have to write
          // temp = row.key + row.value;
          // result.append(temp);
          //row.key + row.value
        }else {
            send(JSON.stringify({
                status_code: 404
            }));
        }
    }
    send(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
}
```